# Get date and time input from text

Tags: java, string, date

So, I was searching for this for some time but I didn't find an answer. Thats why I'm asking here. My problem goes like this:
With Swing I made an app that will get text from JTextArea and then save it inside a .txt document. Also it will save 2 more files (as .txt documents too). In one, there would be date (i.e 2016.03.05) and in other would be time (i.e 09:50 AM). What I need is compare the date and time to system date and time and check if they match. I only need a way on how to exactly do this, since they are stored as string, what would be good way to compare them to system date and time.
I think that is should be like this:

```
if(date in date file is equal to system date) {/do stuff}
```

I wouldn't rly be looking for spoonfeeding, but I need to have a good and efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: Why do you have files? Why do you need 3 files? What sort of file are your Date, and Time files. Do you know how to get the current time of the system?

Comment: I decided to store the data of user's input in diffrent files. In one, there would be JTextArea text. In other, there would be date, and in 3rd there would be time. They are all .txt documents. System.getCurrentTimeMilis(); should work for me, or should it?

Comment: How about Instant.now(). Also you should try to make your example contain real code. Are you having issues reading/writing to the files? Are you having issues getting the values from your Swing GUI? If not then leave out the swing part and past some actual code that you are using to compare the date/time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pretend the op has read the date/time strings from a file.

```
String date = "2016.03.05";
String time = "09:50 AM";
```

We want to compare that to the "system time" so how about.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Now we have a date and time and we want to compare it to the values in the file. One way, is to create a LocalDate object from the date string.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormatter);    
if(now.toLocaleDate().equals(localDate)){
    //date is equal so now what?
}
```

We can do the same for the local time.

```
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m a");
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(time, timeFormatter);
if(now.toLocalTime().equals(localTime)){
   //do stuff if the time is equal (which it will rarely be)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 then there is a very good article on how to parse a String to Date. Once you parse a String into class LocalDateTime then you can then run:

```
if(LocalDateTime.now().equals(yourTime)) {
  //your code
}
```

to see if they match.
Please read about java.time package here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

and here is an article about String parsing to date: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman?trk=pulse_spock-articles